# How to finish child activity when parent activity wants

Tags: android

I am looking to display loading screen until my main activity loads required data from back-end. Therefore I start `LoadingActivity` from my `MainActivity` oncreate method.

After all required data is retrieved from back-end I want to close `LoadingActivity` from `MainActivity`.

How could I do this? Is this a better way to avoid displaying empty screen to user until required data is loaded? Please help me.

Comment: Instead of activity why not using `progress bar` ?

Comment: @Heisen-Berg I just want to display a layout without displaying an actionbar

Comment: Then try to use `fragment` for this task. Fragment provides easy methods for this type of task.

Comment: @Heisen-Berg If I use fragment It would appear with actionbar of `MainActivity` I need to display in a fullscreen

Comment: Why not use ProgressDialog for this purpose? You can use methods like  progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); and   progressDialog.setCancelable(false); to make sure user cannot perform other operations when data from back-end hasnt been loaded yet

Comment: @ChyperX you can easily define `theme` for your `fragment`. So if you want to hide `actionbar` on specific fragment you can do it by defining in theme for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily this type of task with the help of `Fragment`. For example, when you want to start your `LoadingFragment` from your `MainActivitiy` you can start as,

```
LoadingFragment fragment = new LoadingFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(android.R.id.container, fragment);
transaction.commit();
```

Now, you want to make your fragment to be in fullscreen mode. You can easily do this by adding `windowflags` in `onCreateView` method of your fragment as,

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Window w = getActivity().getWindow();
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the MainActvity use a global variable:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@override
void onCreate(){
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog();
//Other initialisations and tasks
progrssDailog.show();
}

//After loading the MainActivity you can simply
progressDialog.dismiss();
```

Finally what you mean by LoadingActivity, is it a custom class by you? is it necessary to use that particular LoadingActivity.